# Polygonal Map not working in rviz

Tags: kinect, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get PolygonalMapDisplay to work in rviz [specifically with the kinect demos] In rviz the polygonal map display says "plugin from package [mapping_rviz_plugin] not loaded for display class [mapping_rviz_plugin::PolygonalMapDisplay])

I've looked around in the file system and can't find any Polygonal Map stuff. Does anyone know where I might be able to find this plugin/how to get polygonal maps to work in rviz?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10153/polygonal-map-not-working-in-rviz./) by [Perchik](https://answers.ros.org/users/643/perchik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem with the kinect.

I solved the problem in this way:

"rosmake mapping_rviz_plugin"

---

Regards

---

Originally posted by [JosèP](https://answers.ros.org/users/660/jos%C3%A8p/) with karma: 36 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Perchik](https://answers.ros.org/users/643/perchik/) on 2011-06-08**:
yep, that did it. Thanks!